# angular Error: $compile:multidir

Tags: angularjs

The following code produces Error: $compile:multidir error:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
...
}]);


app.directive('myDirective', ['$window', '$timeout', function($window, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {

        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {}
...
}]);
```

the html is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" my-directive>
    <div class="index-menu-item" ng-repeat="a in scopeVar">
    </div>
</div>
```

could you tell what is wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can not have two directive on same tag which are creating child scope, like here `ng-controller` & `my-directive` both are placed on same element.

> `ng-controller` directive does create an scope which is prototypically
>   inherited from child scope, It use `scope: true`
>
> `my-directive` directive is creating a isolated scope from current
>   scope

Two isolated scope on same element is not possible, you need to either compile one of the directive by setting `priority: 1001` to higher priority with `terminal: true`, `terminal : true` will ensure that the no other directive will fire after the other.

But doing above things will not work. You need to place you directive inside controller element. That would solve your issue.

Comment: Does the controller create an isolated scope? $scope is passed to its constructor. changing priority does not seem to help

Comment: yes create a scope with `scope: true` which prototypically inherited from parent scope & look at my edit..